# keep getting bad accurcy at testing

Tags: classification, lstm

I don't know what is wrong but I keep getting bad accurcy
i tried to change the no. of epochs, patch_size
adding a drop layer but nothing

[fitting and testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDK3l.png)

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NTNN-ZC8GlpZSIHX4ovttlzqdjwDw-4t?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

First try to normalize the data.
It looks like the case of overfitting ,you are getting much much better accuracy in training data.
Next separate the data further into validation data and use it.
And it would be great if you can share more information (about the data ,the layers you are using , the activation function used) , there are many people here who could help you more if you give proper details and tell them what all you have tried.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NTNN-ZC8GlpZSIHX4ovttlzqdjwDw-4t?usp=sharing

Comment: have a look I did clean the text and tried one hot representation too still having the same problem  I'm quite new so it feels like I don't know what I'm doing